# NPM Scripts using watch works in CLI but breaks in npm scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, watch

I'm trying to set up the following npm scripts on Windows 10 (using git bash, MINGW):

Snippet from `scripts` in my **package.json**:

```
...
"sass:build": "cat assets/styles/* | node-sass | postcss --no-map -u autoprefixer -u cssnano > dist/public/styles/styles.css.min",
"sass:watch": "watch sass:build ./assets/styles/",
...
```

After running `npm i --save-dev node-sass postcss autoprefixer cssnano watch` I get this error:

> $ npm run sass:watch
>
> > thenewells@0.0.0 sass:watch C:\repos\thenewells
>   > watch sass:build ./assets/styles/
>
> >Watching ./assets/styles/
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

But if I do `npm i -g node-sass postcss autoprefixer cssnano watch` then this happens...

> $ watch 'npm run sass:build' ./assets/styles/
>
> > Watching ./assets/styles/
>
> > thenewells@0.0.0 sass:build C:\repos\thenewells
>   > cat assets/styles/* | node-sass | postcss --no-map -u autoprefixer -u cssnano > dist/public/styles/styles.css.min
>
> √ Finished stdin (373ms)

Why does the plain CLI version work, while the npm scripts version error when trying to find the directory?

I've also tried putting 'npm run sass:build' in the sass:watch task. Same effect. I can run sass:build via `npm run sass:build` and that works.

---

**Workaround**

I'm able to define a bash script to run the watch command and it works.

**sass-watch** (no file extension, unix style)

```
watch 'npm run sass:build' ./assets/styles/
```

And now the **sass:watch** job can just be `bash ./sass-watch`.

And that works fine. So I can probably chain that in a more complex script chain so I can get my `npm run dev` to work, but I would rather not have to reach for wrapping scripts in a script for such a strange use-case. It seems like what I wrote in `sass:watch` originally should work... :\

Just another reason to ditch Windows and install Ubuntu...? Or does npm do something to the environment that makes the watch command expect something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try surrounding the command with quotes and see if it works:

```
"sass:watch": "watch \"npm run sass:build\" ./assets/styles/"
```

Explaination:

First of all, it has to be npm run sass:build, not sass:build because that's how you run a npm script you defined.

Secondly, the reason you have to quote the command is that watch is reading command from process.argv using minimist, it treats the first argument as the command, if you don't quote the entire command, it'll be npm, and the rest of arguments are all treated as directories it watches, that's why you get an error saying wrong filename.

Thirdly, I'm not sure why single quotes didn't work, maybe it's a problem related to Windows and Mingw, because the difference between double quotes and single quotes is that one will be evaluated and the other will be treated literally in shell.

Comment: This gave me the correct results without a bash script, could you explain why this works? While surrounding the command in `'`'s doesn't work? (And even `"watch \"sass:build\" ./assets/styles/"` doesn't work too?) As it stands your answer is prescriptive without being very descriptive, which is helpful short term, but I'm going to be writing a lot of npm scripts and would like to gain an understanding of the tool.

Thanks so much!

Comment: @SeanNewell I updated my answer with some explainations

Comment: Thanks a lot!
For some reason I thought the scripts got added to the path when npm started running. #wrong